# Ubuntu -opening android studio after installing from terminal

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio using below commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Now I couldn't find the path where android studio is installed and don't know how to open it?

Comment: did you check in /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 1):

1. cd Downloads //location where installed file located
2. ls
3. cd android-studio/bin
4. ./studio.sh

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, on what is the purpose of each step, and why you are doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

It will not truly 'install'. It is kind of an annoyance for first time users, but it is truly a stand-alone package, it will drop the SDK in your `'/home'` and you need the `'android-studio'` and `'jdk1.8.0_45'` folders at a fixed location.

First, you need to set the 'JAVA_HOME' path in your `/etc/environment` or `~/.bashrc` configuration to the `'jdk1.8.0_45'` folder before it will run.

After setting your `'JAVA_HOME'`, run `'studio.sh'` again and it will boot the IDE. Then at the menu, hit the `'Configure'` button then hit `'Create Desktop Entry'`. You should now have a start menu icon, and desktop icon which you can easily use.

Next time you boot and create a project it should download the SDK required for building.

Answer (score 0):

After installation from `terminal`, luncher icon should be displayed on `unity dash board`. Press the `unity` button ( if it is a windows designed keyboard it is the `windows logo` button in between `alt` and `ctrl`) and search for android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Just type:
`/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`
and hit enter.